# Angular custom directive: Access parent scope property in linking function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to set the name of an event (click or touch) on a parent scope in angular as a string. On a child scope I want to use that string to bind an event with element.on.

Example:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('Sidebar', function () {
        'use strict';

        return {
            link: function (scope) {
                //determines whether or not to use click or touch events
                //I want to use this to bind events with 
                //element.on(scope.sidebarClickEvent) in child scopes          
                scope.sidebarClickEvent = 'click';
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'sidebar.html'
        };
    })
    .directive('collapseBtn', function() {
        'use strict';

        return function (scope, element) {
            element.on(scope.sidebarClickEvent /* undefined */ , function () {
                //scope.sidebarClickEvent is available here, when the event handler executes
                scope.toggleSidebarCollapseState();
                element.find('i').toggleClass('icon-double-angle-right');
            });

        };
    })
```

The problem is that properties defined on the parent scope aren't available when I bind the events, so scope.sidebarClickEvent is undefined when I bind the event. But if I change it to a regular click event then I can get the property in the event handler.

Can I access properties inherited by the scope at the time that the event binding occurs? I'm not even sure that I'm understanding scope inheritance properly here, so pointing out errors in my understanding would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the HTML where Sidebar and collapseBtn are used?

Comment: use scope.$parent.sidebarClickEvent